# Nette Framework - Get Current Session ID

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, nette

I need to get an **ID of current session**. Using httpRequest's cookies is not a good idea because session gets regenerated after login or by whatever action.

I also tried Session class but for getting a session ID it is needed to specify a section which Nette uses to split the application. However I couldn't find out the section name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's method `getSession()` available in a presenter, so for accessing the session ID you can use:

```
$sessionId = $this->getSession()->getId();
```